# How can I recognize Mir runing on tablet/phone running Ubuntu Touch Saucy Salamander?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, mir

Phones and tablets behaves differently from ubuntu on desktop. So this is why mir can not be found the same way however the system with [Ubuntu Touch Saucy Salamander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Touch#Release) does run on [Mir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_%28software%29). There isn't any Unity-system-compositor running on my system. I do see `unity8` and `lightdm` running.

Answer (score 2):

On a phone or tablet, run `ps aux | grep SurfaceFlinger`, and if you don't see a process by that name then you're running Mir